# Running mvn install from Dockerfile gives error but, running it from inside the container is successful

Tags: docker, maven, build, docker-compose

I have a project at https://github.com/picklu13/dockerbuildtest. 
When I run `docker-compose up --build` from the `builders` directory, the build errors with "[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/app). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]"

Now if I comment out the last line of the Dockerfile 
`# RUN mvn clean package` and run `docker-compose up --build`, the container starts up.
Then I go into the container with `docker exec -it <id> bash` and run `mvn clean install` which succeeds.

My question is, why did the first build fail with no pom.xml error although it was already present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first case, you're running `build` from `builders` directory but the [context](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#understand-build-context) passed to Docker does not contains `pom.xml` (it contains what is in your current directory as per `docker-compose` instruction `context: .`)

In your second case, `up` will mount your project's directory in `app` with:

```
 volumes:
      - ~/dockerbuildtest/:/app/
```

Meaning that `~/dockerbuildtest/pom.xml` will appear in container as `/app/pom.xml`. Running `mvn` from `app` now works.

> why did the first build fail with no pom.xml error although it was already present

It was *not* present: in first build, there is no `pom.xml` copied into your image (see [`COPY`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) instruction).

You could ensure your context contains `pom.xml` by running your build command from your project's root directory and specifying Dockerfile such as:

```
    build:
      # will use current directory as build context
      # by running from your project's root dir, context will contain pom.xml
      context: .
      # path to Dockerfile is relative to where build command is run
      dockerfile: builders/Dockerfile
```

And copy your `pom.xml` in your Dockerfile such as:

```
# [...]
WORKDIR /app

# copy pom.xml from context into image
COPY pom.xml /app/pom.xml

# run from /app directory which now contains a pom.xml, should work
RUN mvn clean package
```

Comment: When docker-compose is used to mount a volume, then do we assume that the mounting happens after the build-steps?

Comment: Yes definitely, whether you use a bind mount or a volume on Compose it will be mounted in container at runtime, not during build. There is a notion of `VOLUME` during build-time, but then again the real volume will be created at runtime (see docs: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume). There is also the possibility to use sort of volumes specific to build with experimental features (see https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/) but it is very different than volumes you would specify with `services.[service].volumes:` in Compose

Answer (score 1):

You mount a volume and I think by the time the container boots up, the specified resource is not at said location, due to the volume not yet being loaded.

You could try to not use a volume and instead use a COPY command in your dockerfile to make sure the resource is actually in /app before the container starts.

[EDIT]
Even if you scenario does not allow you to do so, I recommend still testing with the COPY to see if this indeed is a volume problem.